# How to use GroupBy and IQueryable together and map to DTO?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Scenario:

I am in need to fetch some records from Database and I need to group them by CreationDate

```
IQueryable<AlbumDTO> albums = (from c in context.Albums.where(x =>x.SingerID==1)
.orderBy<x =>x.AlbumDate>.groupBy(x => x.AlbumDate)
select new AlbumsDTO()).Take(10));
```

> But how do I fetch AlbumNames by using this query?

Because if I do

```
 select new AlbumDTO()
 {
    AlbumName = //nothing comes here and throws error
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing comes here*?

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this:

```
context.Albums.Where(x=>x.SinderID==1)
    .OrderBy(x =>x.AlbumDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.AlbumDate)
    .Select(_ => new AlbumsDTO{AlbumName = _.AlbumName});
```

?

in my understanding of linq - you are not populating your `AlbumDTO` objects, but just initializing them.

the way i populate your `AlbumDTO` objects in the linq query - assumes `AlbumName` - is a property that has both public setter and public getter:

```
public class AlbumDTO
{
    public string AlbumName {get;set;}
}
```